# Running a t-sql job step (stored procedure) with a proxy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, proxy, jobs

I have a database job that executes the stored procedure `spImport` as one job step daily.

[image: Job step]

I have a proxy called `SPImporter`. I'd like this proxy to execute the job step above. But in the dropdownlist under "Run as:" there are no values because there's no choice "Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)" in the list under "Active to the following subsystems:".

My proxy:

[image]

What do I have to do to execute the job step with the proxy?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this might help you..https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/

Comment: I've had a look at it but when I change the type of the job step to "SQL Server Integration Services Package" I can't chose my stored procedure.

Comment: @diiN_ because SSIS are *.DTS packages created by integration projects in Business Development Studio (or Visual Studio). And the package can execute procedures as a step itself. I would recommend to use the packages, there are many options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem.

I granted `spImporter` rights to the subsystem `Operating system (CmdExec)` and changed the type of the job step also to `Operating system (CmdExec)`. After that the command for the step had to be changed to `SQLCMD -Q"EXEC dbo.spImport" -E -S [ServerName]`.